# AttributeError: datetime.date object has no Attribute '__dict__'

Tags: python

```
resp = web.Response(body=json.dumps(r, cls=CJsonEncoder, ensure_ascii=False, default=lambda o: o.__dict__).encode('utf-8'))
```

when I used jinja2, and retrieve date form MYSQL, but the error shown.
data:

```
2015-09-01
2015-09-04
```

how to fix it?
may i need convert jinja2 to django??

Comment: when I change the type date to type varchar(50) of MYSQL, the result is normal.

Comment: well your data contains `date` objects, and your `default` is to use an object's `__dict__`, and `date` objects don't have a `__dict__`.  write a smarter `default` function.

Comment: no, apparently, use type varchar is valid, I think the serialization is the point. because datetime.date can not  Serializable. thanks!

Comment: i strongly recommend against using the wrong types in your database just to avoid this problem in python

Answer (score 10):

This has nothing to do with Django or Jinja2 or your Web framework.  Your data contains `date` objects, and JSON has no date type, so the `json` module doesn't know how to store them.  It tries to fall back to your `default` function, which just dumps all of an object's attributes, but the `date` type is implemented in C and doesn't have a Python dict of attributes.

You can fix this by expanding upon your `default`:

```
import datetime

def json_default(value):
    if isinstance(value, datetime.date):
        return dict(year=value.year, month=value.month, day=value.day)
    else:
        return value.__dict__

resp = web.Response(body=json.dumps(r, cls=CJsonEncoder, ensure_ascii=False, default=json_default).encode('utf-8'))
```

I recommend *against* using `.__dict__` as a catch-all fallback, though — your output might contain private junk, and your JSON may not produce anything like your original data when decoded.